# How To fix this problem when installing PyQt5

Tags: python, powershell, pip, pyqt5

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

Installez la dernière version de PowerShell pour de nouvelles fonctionnalités et améliorations ! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS D:\Python Algorithmes> pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\nabil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u51cxzuf\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'sip >=6.4, <7' 'PyQt-builder >=1.9, <2'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (125 lines):
  Collecting sip<7,>=6.4
    Using cached
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting PyQt-builder<2,>=1.9
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/55/db354bd9dfa613c8f8f6ecb81617caefdfb3e77befba098f8e14ed95e385/PyQt_builder-1.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting setuptools (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/02/8d4d27b1cacaac2d129a27d17a22d92a2a5eedcb7817d4ed8ab0d4daf5c4/setuptools-60.9.3-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting packaging (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/8e/8de486cbd03baba4deef4142bd643a3e7bbe954a784dc1bb17142572d127/packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting toml (from sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/6f/7120676b6d73228c96e17f1f794d8ab046fc910d781c8d151120c3f1569e/toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 (from packaging->sip<7,>=6.4)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/c1/23fd82ad3121656b585351aba6c19761926bb0db2ebed9e4ff09a43a3fcc/pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl
  Building wheels for collected packages: sip
    Building wheel for sip (PEP 517): started
    Building wheel for sip (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\nabil\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzka__y5g'
         cwd: C:\Users\nabil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z3bacb11\sip
    Complete output (95 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\abstract_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\abstract_project.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\argument_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\bindings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\buildable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\configurable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\distutils_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\installable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\project.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\pyproject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\py_versions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\setuptools_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    copying sipbuild\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\distinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    copying sipbuild\distinfo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\distinfo
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\abi_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    copying sipbuild\module\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\install.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\sdist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\wheel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    copying sipbuild\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\tools
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\apiversions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\objmap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\qtlib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\README.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sipint.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\siplib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\threads.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    copying sipbuild\module\source\12\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\12
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\objmap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\README.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sipint.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\siplib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\threads.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    copying sipbuild\module\source\13\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sipbuild\module\source\13
    running build_ext
    building 'sipbuild.code_generator' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\code_generator
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icode_generator "-Ic:\program files\python38\include" "-Ic:\program files\python38\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tccode_generator\export.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\code_generator\export.obj
    export.c
    code_generator\export.c(20): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'stdio.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
    Running setup.py clean for sip
  Failed to build sip
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\nabil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u51cxzuf\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'sip >=6.4, <7' 'PyQt-builder >=1.9, <2' Check the logs for full command output.
PS D:\Python Algorithmes>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip3:

`pip3 install PyQt5`